# Python : Handling multiple telnet sessions to same IP

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I have few list of commands (any number), which have to be executed over telnet on one particular IP/HOST. And the output to be stored in separate file. These commands are specific to log collection.

```
 I need them in such a way that, Execute all those required commands at once (Start/enabling for log collection) - Multiple telnet sessions, one session per command. After sometime (Not a timed activity), require another script to stop all of them & logs stored in separate file respectively (based on the list of commands executed).

 I could able to do it only for one particular command, that too only for short interval of time.
```

I hope I'm clear with the details. Please let me know if you are not clear with the concept. Please help me in this regard.

```
import sys
import telnetlib
import time

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

try:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(IP)
    tn.read_until(b"login: ")
    tn.write(username.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.read_until(b"# ")
    tn.write(command1.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    #time.sleep(30)
    z = tn.read_until(b'abcd\b\n',4)    >> Just a random pattern, so that it reads for long duration.
    #z=tn.read_very_eager()
    output = z.splitlines( )
except:
    sys.exit("Telnet Failed to ",IP)

for i in output:
    i=i.strip().decode("utf-8")
    print(i)

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

Comment: and what have you tried? where are you failing?

Comment: @ Doon : I have provided a snippet above. It is applicable only to single command and i could not collect the logs for long duration. This is to be applied for multiple commands & should be able to collect as long as i wish. In general, One script to start execute the command and another one to stop it.

Comment: so what fails exactly? What is the error?  does the connection close?

Comment: It fails when there is no response from telnet. There are some instances, where it will be paused for a while and again starts displaying logs.

Comment: your current read_until says to read_until you see `abcd` or 4  seconds.(Timeout) is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah. Timeout may be for a small time where it's pausing in between. But how to stop/kill/halt this particular telnet session, when not aware of time how long it should be collecting logs.